# Not convert a field in logstash config file

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I have the typical issue with ELK when I want to have a map in my Kibana 4.0

I create the next index:

```
 curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/igual -d '
 {
   "mappings": {
    "igual": {
        "properties": {
            "localizacion": {"type": "geo_point"},
            "amount": {"type": "float"},
            "days": {"type": "float"}
        }
    }
}
}'
```

Then I want to use Logstash to insert information in my index. But I don't want that the field `localizacion` was parsed.

```
input {  
  file {
      path => "/home/cloudera/Desktop/ultimo.csv"
      start_position => "beginning"
  }
 }

filter {  
csv {
     columns =>      ["center",.......]
    separator => ";"
 }


mutate {
    convert => [ "amount", "float" ]
 }  
mutate {
convert => [ "days", "float" ]
}  
}

 output {  
    elasticsearch {
       action => "index"
       hosts => "localhost"
       index => "igual"
    }
 }
```

My problem is that Logstash tries to parsed `localizacion` from geopoint to string, but I dont want that. I need that Logstash doesnn't parse the field.

Thanks for all. Any idea?

Comment: What does your input look like? E.g. what is 'localizacion' ?

Comment: Localizacion is an array of values (lat,lon).